# Remove overlay in bitmap image

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

In my C# win form, I capture the live bitmap image from direct show and save as JPEG format. The original image consists of an overlay white-colour arrow sign with black rectangle box. Is there a way I can remove overlay image Or Can I chop out the rectangle area only from its original image.  The following is my sample photo.

[image]

Update

```
using TouchlessLib;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

TouchlessMgr manager;
Camera choosenCam;


   //Giving the feed of the camera to the picturebox

   void CurrentCamera_OnImageCaptured(object sender, CameraEventArgs e)
    {

        picFeed.Image = manager.CurrentCamera.GetCurrentImage();
    }


   // Save picturebox image in location 
  Bitmap b = (Bitmap)picFeed.Image;
  picFeed.Image.Save(Paths + imageName + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: I think your camera fell over

Comment: Of course it's possible, but how are you storing the image object? A little code would help a lot.

Comment: @QuestionMarks I have already updated my code. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for looking it up @QuestionMarks